# Javascript function closure - access updated variable value in return statement

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a nested function similar to the one below:

```
function counter() {
  let count = 0;

  function increment() {
    count++;
  }

  return {
    count: () => count,
    increment: increment
  };
}

const myCounter = counter();
myCounter.increment();
console.log(myCounter.count())
```

This appears to work fine but is there any way to return the updated `count` as just the value instead of a function? Ideally the goal is to be able to access the updated count with just `myCounter.count` instead of `myCounter.count()`

Comment: Your function `count: () => count` is a function that returns by value.

Comment: @TLane Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Your function returns by a copy of count. The lambda function you have returns by value, and it cannot do any sort of this-pointer binding. If you want an object with a function that returns an incremented copy, make it like so: `counter = {count: 0, increment: function(){return ++this.count;}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [*getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), which is a function which is called if you use the property.

```js
function counter() {
  let count = 0;

  function increment() {
    count++;
  }

  return {
    get count() { return count },
    increment
  };
}

const myCounter = counter();
myCounter.increment();
console.log(myCounter.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ES6 class`, [getter setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to simplify.

```js
class Counter {
  constructor(){
    this._count = 0
  }
  increment() {
    this._count++;
  }
  get count(){
    return this._count;
  }
}


const myCounter = new Counter();
myCounter.increment();
myCounter.increment();
console.log(myCounter.count)
```

Comment: True, but OP is (currently, at least) working specifically with the code provided. It may or may not be trivial to adjust the code they're using.

Comment: @DaveNewton It s safe and `secure` and more `readable`. compare to function. and less error-prone like this. not found. I don't see any point not suggesting something better to learn. I have written also, using ES6. Else it can be done using defined property, which is more complex to understand

Comment: Let's OP to deside whether he/she want to learn new thing, rather than stick to old thing.

Comment: My point is simple: showing an alternative is fine, but does not directly answer the question (and the more-appropriate answer shows that it's not any more complex).